# How to completely disable SSH commenting?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, openssh

I am trying to completely disable SSH comments.

Running `ssh-keygen -C "" -f test` results in:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f test.pub

3072 SHA256:Ir9Q4ykMBl0zx/NaCQGGx/qmEFIX84qaHDzFA0SzevE no comment (RSA) # (1) no comment

ssh-keygen -l -f test

3072 SHA256:Ir9Q4ykMBl0zx/NaCQGGx/qmEFIX84qaHDzFA0SzevE test.pub (RSA)   # (2) comment!

ssh-keygen -e -f test.pub

---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "3072-bit RSA, converted by cppbest@home from OpenSSH"          # (3) comment!
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQC2PJOMG6g3qpX02Rki5hfqU6//fw78xhyK6tKLqm
piJyI3uD9P5W2nzblJ7dk+B85PTM6c6S95Qq47UBcMnALXCIQ6kRazoZDOaUk9f/BxbEIg
kCaJWX5CVEib52lyF2jH/FEs5kIUJW40II1RVYfWdMKqd08ZPPfAUt6MUj3Rac7d7PHQT5
Cns8zfgba0GIHqktZQYC1oqRfhSTZtvkeX9zTXfZq3DXJ7vJBnNB+r/GddnrU2BkRqlLDw
tVN8WOS8dJvULzMjTJxMwCdIpWXcmN2n3HVBASZom8OCEEaCAFN1QCd9JmqFDAZzio8ZK/
0Q/RvW1o5udhC77JnFye+u8brfT0IENhs5LefcxfKEEdwcD+8ofcEfmxGzIggkvNGYXH14
Z83Cmwla17QmwRSTpKQnv/DYaVncXvkltDkylfhWNzd3yTC73L52aSbzuVlxjqX8LYr6Ir
LwzrQ9ZyNzaWivlgxMPaYJlui1kewd1/n+hTW304SUQ/UOeMbUCRU=
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Is it possible to disable the comments in 2 and 3 too?

Comment: If `man ssh-keygen` doesn't show any option for it (did you check?), the simplest way is to post-process it with something that strips the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some RTFS and it looks like printing comments is hardcoded for the most part.

(1) `ssh-keygen` prints comments like `comment ? comment : "no comment"` so that's where the "no comment" comes from.

(2) `ssh-keygen` checks for presence of `test.pub` by itself, it opens and validates the file even though it was not given on the command line. And then it sets comment like `cp ? cp : filename` so it defaults to the filename instead of "no comment".

So that is where the `test.pub` comment comes from. Move `test.pub` away and the result changes.

(3) it's completely hard-coded with no option to disable (short of changing the `-m format` from SSH2 to something else). You have to remove it with an external filter.

Comment: Surely this works then `ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdout | grep -v '^Comment: ' > test.pub` (at least for 3)